# Adding Base URL in react.js project is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to add the base URL to my react.js project.
However I had tried couple of methods that did not work.

**For example, if my project url is :**

```
http://www.myproject.com/
```

**It should appear in address bar as :**

```
http://www.myproject.com/app
http://www.myproject.com/app/home  // If home page 
http://www.myproject.com/app/about // If about page
```

**Below is my project code.**

**index.js**

```
import "./index.css"
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthProvider';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import { disableReactDevTools } from '@fvilers/disable-react-devtools';
import App from './App';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  disableReactDevTools();
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**App.js**

```
import Layout from './components/authController/Layout'
import Login from './components/authController/Login';
import Home from './components/authController/Home'
import AllUser from './components/authController/AllUser'
import RequireAuth from './components/authController/RequireAuth';
import PersistLogin from './components/authController/PersistLogin';
import Logout from './components/authController/Logout';
import Missing from './Missing';
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          {/* public routes */}
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="loggedOut" element={<Logout />} />
          
        {/* we want to protect these routes */}
        <Route element={<PersistLogin />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<Home/>} />

            <Route element={<RequireAuth/>}>
              <Route path="alluser" element={<AllUser />} />
            </Route>

        </Route>
          {/* catch all */}
          <Route path="*" element={<Missing />} />
      </Route>
  </Routes>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**What I had tried?**

As I referred in stackoverflow and also many other websites, integrated below methods.

1. Added base url inside *package.json* file
   `"homepage": "/app",`
2. Tried to pass the tag `<base href="http://myapp.com/app">` within `<head>` tag in *public/index.html page*
3. Passed the base url within BrowserRouter in *index.js* `<BrowserRouter basename="app"> </BrowserRouter>`

I am sure I am missing something, it would be great learning if someone help on this or give insights on this.

Thank you

Comment: Is your react app *actually* deployed to *and served from* a `"/app"` directory on the server? The `basename` prop is a way to prefix routes/links automatically to match the directory where the app is served from.

Comment: i think the best way is to redirect users from `/` to `/app`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the correct answer to this , but I believe that you can redirect the route "/" to "/app" . I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:-**

Hello everyone.

I got the solution for my query.
I have modified the ***index.js*** file like below

```
 <Routes>
     <Route path="app/*" element={<App />} />
     <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="app/home" replace />} />
 </Routes>
```